# Encontrar o indice de um determinado valor em uma lista em Python

Tags: python

Galera, Estou fazendo uma função para contar as palavras de um texto sem repeti-las e com isso, também preciso contar quantas vezes ela aparece dentro dessa lista de strings usei o código abaixo mas ele não funciona, eu não consigo pegar a posição da palavra na minha lista de palavras para fazer referencia numa outra lista que só vou armazenar a quantidade de vezes que ela aparece. Obs: eu preciso disso para respeitar a posição da palavra com referencia a posição.
Ex: palavras[1] = 'casa'
    frequencia[1] = 3

def frequencia(listaTweets):

```
    palavras = []
    freq_palavras = []
    for x in range(len(listaTweets)):
            tweet = listaTweets[x]
            listaP = separa_palavras(tweet)
            for p in listaP:
                    if p in palavras:
                            indice = palavras.index(p)
                            freq_palavras[indice] += 1
                    else:
                            palavras.append(p)              
    return palavras, freq_palavras
```

Comment: O código atual me retorna este erro: freq_palavras[indice] += 1
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Olá Jhonatan! Você pode [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/212076/edit) sua pergunta para incluir novas informações! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vou resolver a questão para vc, mas la vai algumas dicas:

**Verificando se um elemento está dentoro de uma lista:**

```
>>> 5 in [1,2,3,4,5]
True
```

**Usando index:**

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5].index(2)
3
```

**procurando por um certo elemento:**

```
>>> lst = ['josé', 'maria', 'joão', 'josé']
>>> [(n, lst[n]) for n, x in enumerate(lst) if x=='josé']
[(0, 'josé'), (3, 'josé')]
```

Nessa o resultado é uma lista de tuplas com a palavra e a posição (index) na lista original.

**Agora uma para 'extrair' os elementos sem as repetições:**

```
>>> lst = ['josé', 'maria', 'joão', 'josé']
>>> s = set()
>>> unique = [x for x in lst if x not in s and not s.add(x)]    
>>> print(unique)
['josé', 'maria', 'joão']
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui!

Comment: Se vc conseguiu com a resposta, considere dar o aceite. :-)

Comment: Perdão, comecei a pouco usar o stackoverflow, não sei muita coisa ainda... Acabei de aceitar, desculpa.